# Where is the firebase crashlytics plugin source code

Tags: android, crashlytics

I want to configure the location of my google-services.json file.
I have a dual dimension structure, and i don't want to have dimension1Dimension2 folder

I want to put my google-services.json file only in dimension2 folder.

How can I look at the logic which decides where this json file is?
I've looked all over, and can only find the firebase-crashlytics-sdk
but I want to find the firebase-crashlytics-plugin

the one I add here:         `classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2'`